# Python Colored Heatmap Doesn't Display Data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, plot, heatmap

Following this script: https://gist.github.com/teechap/9c066a9ab054cc322877 I am trying to create a heatmap of values from a csv. Data reads in just fine and arrays are created, even the plot is drawn but no actual colors are displayed. From what I can tell however, the axis are within the correct ranges.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec

filein = open('test.csv', 'r')
data = csv2rec(filein, names=['x', 'y'])
x = data['x']
y = data['y']

intensity = np.random.randn(len(data['x']),len(data['y']))

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

intensity = np.array(intensity)

plt.pcolormesh(x, y, intensity)
plt.colorbar() 
plt.show()
```

test.csv looks like:

```
3,4.32192809489
3,3.16992500144
3,2.32192809489
3,2.0
3,5.90689059561
```

My intention is to have a lot more datapoints, around 100, but as you can see from the following image that it doesn't actually display the data.

[image: non-working-heatmap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be that all of your x-coordinates are the same (3).  Your code seemed to plot OK for me when I edited the first column of your input values.

The original code that you link to works fine.

Comment: I don't start seeing variation in my X coordinates until around 5000 datapoints. I never ran a test on a set that large until now. @Paul J thank you for pointing this out.